# Jenkins with JSLint and Violations plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jslint

I currently configured a jenkins server that validates my project on javascript errors with JSlint ( with ant). Now i want to show all the errors with the violation plugin. I can generate an xml with all the errors. But it doesn't show this in the graph.

This is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<taskdef name="jslint"
       classname="com.googlecode.jslint4java.ant.JSLintTask"
       classpath="jslint/jslint4java-2.0.2.jar" />

<property name="reports.dir" value="reports" />

<target name="clean" description="Removes output files created by other targets.">
    <delete dir="${reports.dir}" failonerror="true" />
</target>

<target name="jslint" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="reports" />
    <jslint options="white,undef,plusplus,newcap,vars,indent=4">
        <predef>jQuery, setTimeout, history, window, document</predef>
        <formatter type="xml" destfile="jslint_results.xml"/> 
        <fileset dir="" includes="**/*.js" excludes="lib/*.js" />
    </jslint>
</target>
```

This is my violations setting:

[image: violations settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is relative to your workspace. So if your report 'lives' in `<WORKSPACE>/reports` the pattern should be `reports/jslint_results.xml` or `**/jslint_results.xml`

Comment: The reports cleaning etc, is a residu off an old script   the jslint_results.xml is generated in the main folder of my workspace...

Comment: yes , i can BUT for some reason it just started working when i put in a reports folder ... so thank you very very much :DDDDD

Comment: Do you perhaps how i can keep records for every build ?
Now it only shows for my last build

Comment: I do not know offhand - need to research it. In any case, I think it is worth asking as a separate question.